# Restricting user access to a subset of binaries

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, access-control-list, user-management

I checked `rbash` and `chroot jail`, which doesn't have permission to read /var/log.

Scenario:

ssh user should only able to cd to a directory and do less for files.

eg:

```
ssh user@server.com
cd /var/log
less application.log
```

In short an user with global filesystem access with only one binary like `less` or `more` to read the file.

Comment: That's not very useful. What about `tail` or `grep`? or `cut`? Or hundreds of other useful things one might do with log files.

Comment: Less is just a binary. Any such binary will suffice.